# Processing a file then uploading it : nodejs / formidable

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, upload, formidable

I'm using the npm package `formidable` to:

1. Check the content of a file
2. If the content satisfies the condition, the file upload can be done; otherwise, reject the request with an error message

Here's the layout of my code:

```js
import Formidable from 'formidable';

const form = new Formidable({
    uploadDir: 'myFolder',
    allowEmptyFiles: false,
    keepExtensions: true,
});

form.on('fileBegin', (formname, file) => {
    // Changing the filename
});

let canUploadFile = false;

form.onPart = (part) => {
    // Checking if the filename is mentioned in the file content
    // If so, upload the file
    // Else, reject and send a 400 HTTP response
    const dmnFileName = path.basename(part?.filename ?? '', '.dmn');
    part.on('data', (buffer) => {
      // do whatever you want here
      const bufferData = Buffer.from(buffer).toString();
      const parser = new htmlparser2.Parser({
        onopentag(name: any, attributes: any) {
          // check is done here by setting canUploadFile
        },
      });
      parser.write(bufferData);
      parser.end();
    });
};
  
  
form.parse(req, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
      return;
    }
    logger.info(`File is being parsed...`);
});

form.on('end', async function () {
    if(canUploadFile) {
        res.send({ message: 'File uploaded!' });
    } else {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: 'The file cannot be uploaded',
        });
    }   
}
```

WhenI execute this code, the file doesn't get uploaded, but when I remove the `form.onPart`, the file gets uploaded!

What am I missing?